# Linux Software RAID - Migrate from disk device to a partition

Tags: linux, raid, migration, mdadm

I have two 8TB disks configured as RAID1 using `mdadm` on Ubuntu 18.04 server. They way I created software RAID was on the whole device - `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc` - instead of the partition such as `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1`.

The problem is, the RAID does not assemble on reboot and the only way to get back the `md` devices is by recreating - running the same command used to create the RAID1 volume initially. I've read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860643/raid-array-doesnt-reassemble-after-reboot) that for the `md` device to assemble automatically upon reboot one needs to create RAID on partitions instead of the whole device .

I have LVM on top of the RAID1 and use it as store for VMs managed using Ganeti. I already have few VMs running and using about 2TB of the total 7.6TB capacity.

If I create a partition on these disks spanning the whole device and create RAID again as I currently do, is there hope in getting back the LVM and the partitions on it?

Comment: I tried to test this out under VirtualBox using 10GB disks and it looks like this is not possible. After recreating RAID on the new partitions I do not get back the volume group.

Comment: This is doable, but high risk. You need to back up first, then ensure the LVM has space free at the end, then shrink RAID (using --grow ! ) then finish a full rebuild RAID, remove first disk, partition, add back.

Comment: I should have explicitly stated you need to shrink the PV under LVM.

Comment: @davidgo Shrinking RAID and rebuilding makes sense. I will try this.